# Need to apply for "titre de séjour" within two months of arrival but no available appointment at prefecture

Tags: resident-permit, france, students

I'm currently doing my PhD in France, and I arrived using a type D visa, which states that I need to apply for "titre de séjour" within two months of arrival. To do this, I'm supposed to make an appointment with the concerned prefecture - and the problem is that the prefecture is booked for the next three months! This is a paradoxical situation since I'm supposed to do something which is not possible in given circumstances. Does anyone have experience with such scenarios? If yes, how did you manage it?

To clarify, my employer/university is the entity which will ask for an appointment on my behalf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By making an appointment to apply for "titre de séjour", you will showing your intention to comply with the requirement.

Unfortunately it is now common place in many places **not** to be able to get an appointment within the required timeframe and these institutions are very aware of that.

Most online appointment systems require you to give the **reason** for the appointment, such as

- apply for "titre de séjour"

and by making the appointment, the application process has started.
Making a pdf copy (or print out) of the appointment is advised.

This may differ from administration to administration, but in Germany now the date the appointment (where your name and reason is given)  was made is what counts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It seems that for the first time application, I cannot make an appointment by myself either. My only fear now is that by the time the appointments for next year will open, my visa would have already been expired.

Comment: @Siddharth If the employer must apply, they should do so and also ask about this.  This is something they should know about (or at least want to learn about).

Comment: Indeed, if your employer is sponsoring you they should be able to make the appointment for you.  Mine has done that in the past.  And yes, with many of these processes, they do recognize that it is not your fault if you cannot do something "in time" due to existing administrative delays.  As long as you officially signal your intent in time, e.g. by taking the soonest available appointment they offer, you should be okay.  Make sure you get a record of the appointment (e.g. they might send it by e-mail).

Comment: Forgot an update. I did get an appointment (managed by the employer) - now I'm just waiting for the decision/card.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to apply for ‘titre de sejour’? I might be wrong but in most long stay visas you need to validate your visa online and the process follows.
This is what I did for my appointments. I received the medical appointment in a week of arrival but still waiting for OFII summon.
Your process might differ but worth checking.